# Can't get into CMOS setup on MSI MB 970a-g46

Tags: motherboard, bios, cmos

I can't seem to get to bios any more. barely see the MSI logo flash by, no setup message that I see that I've read about. The delete button is access to it. This is an MSI 970a-g46 motherboard, Windows 8 64, 4 core amd 3.8ghz.

Answer (score 1):

What's causing this is the new fastboot option - [MS has a writeup about this](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/b8/archive/2012/05/22/designing-for-pcs-that-boot-faster-than-ever-before.aspx)

open up settings, then go to "Change PC Settings" -> "General" and pick "Advanced start up"

This should reboot you into the new windows 8 bootloader - which is metro style. Select "troubleshoot" and "UEFI firmware Settings"

Comment: That's a better answer!

Comment: ok love the article. Now tell me how I get this computer to give the ability to get to BIOS. I've looked at all of the stuff and there are no options that "I" can find that says infactially this will give me the ability to get to BIOS. I have no UEFI firmware settings thing. Thanks for the article and the answer!!!!!

Comment: hold shift key and go restart get to the blue screen, got refresh pc, reset pc, advanced options.   Go to advanced options I get, system restore, system image recovery, auto repair, command prompt, advanced settings.

Comment: ok it is start up settings, not advanced settings after command prompt.  blue screen go to troubleshoot pc, then go to refresh pc thing and such.

Answer (score 0):

Try disconnecting the hard drive so Windows 8 will stop hijacking the startup?

Comment: ok tried the unplug thing. Didn't do anything. Gonna try the keep del button down thing to.

Comment: Ok, so BIOS will start up if OS isn't there??  Just to add have not done any updates to bios. At one point I was able to get to it. When I first got it up an running.

Comment: Just to add to Debra's suggestion below: after physically unplugging, hold the power button down for 5 seconds to discharge the PSU before re-plug and restart.

Comment: This seems more like a comment. I'd suggest [edit]ing it to explain why Windows 8 loads so fast that the OP can't access his BIOS

Comment: well its been awhile since posted this but the delete button seems to be the way to get it to go to the bios. have used it too. or the clickbios2 shortcut works too in admin mode.

Answer (score 0):

Completely power down the system and remove the power cable.  Then re-plug and restart;  you should now see the initial startup including the option to get into setup.

Another way that sometimes works is to restart and simply sit on the [Del] key until the keyboard buffer fills;  that will almost always get you a prompt to go into setup, because the system will think something might be wrong with the keyboard.

Windows 8 doesn't do a true power-down when you shut down or restart, which is why it's flashing by so fast (if at all).  So to force a true power-down, you have to make it really shut off.